# Handle unreachable server when using Fetch API with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, networking, fetch

In my react native app, the server is specified by the user. Although I put some control on the "url" field, sometimes the user put an url which simply does not exist.
Then, I got a TypeError:

> Network request failed

How can I handle these case in my code?

Thank you

Comment: How do you want to handle this case?

Comment: @TypeIA I just want to display an error message instead of having a weird flashy red screen that follow the... "crash". Maybe I just not understand the way to manage typeerror?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the error case in .then for fetch API.

For example:

```
fetch('...URL')
.then(
  (response) => {
    console.log('success',response)
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log('error',err)
  }
);
```

Comment: Don't forget to also check [`response.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok).

Comment: `err` still holds just a generic `TypeError: Failed to fetch` message, it does not distinguish between `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`, `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`, etc... that you can see in browser console. Sadly separating them programmatically [appears to be impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556398/how-to-catch-neterr-connection-refused).