# How can I POST REST API using React JS and Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I tried many times but am getting the following error

> http://localhost:3001/getLocaiton net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and
>   createError (createError.js:17) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError
>   (xhr.js:87.

How can I solve this issue.

```
axios.post ('http://localhost:3001/getLocaiton' , {
      name: keyWord,

    })  

    .then (function (response){
      console.log (response);
    })

    .catch (function (error){
      console.log (error)
    });
```

Following is the code for node back-end

```
    const express = require ('express');
    const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
    const cors = require ('cors');
    const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
    const client = new Client ();
    const http = require('http')

    const app = express ();
    app.use(cors())

    app.use (bodyParser.urlencoded ({extended :false}))
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    const server = http.createServer(app)
    server.listen(port)


    app.post ('/getLocaiton' , (req, res) =>{
        const typeWord = req.body.name;

        client.get ('https://api.adform.com/v1/help/buyer/advertisers= '+typeWord+"&key=", function (data, response){
            console.log (data);

            console.log (response);
        })
    })

    app.listen (3001, ()=> {
        console.log ("listining to port 3001")
    })
```

Comment: this might help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556398/how-to-catch-neterr-connection-refused

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are starting two servers instances by listening on two ports, but I commented out first port listening and you must return respond to your `/getLocaiton` request (by the way there is a typo in path name):

```
const express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const cors = require ('cors');
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
const client = new Client ();
const http = require('http')

const app = express ();
app.use(cors())

app.use (bodyParser.urlencoded ({extended :false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// const server = http.createServer(app)
// server.listen(port)


app.post ('/getLocaiton' , (req, res) =>{
    const typeWord = req.body.name;
    client.get('https://api.adform.com/v1/help/buyer/advertisers='+
        typeWord+
        "&key=",function (data, response){
            console.log (data);
            console.log (response);
            // you must return your response to your request
            res.json({
                data: data
            })
        }
    )
})

app.listen (3001, ()=> {
    console.log ("listining to port 3001")
})
```

Comment: I have tried this code but still I getting following error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.adform.com/v1/help/buyer/advertisers/getLocaiton' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and 

xhr.js:173 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://api.adform.com/v1/help/buyer/advertisers/getLocaiton with MIME type text/html.

Comment: It is CORS error and it seems related to the API you are requesting on `api.adform.com`