# How to get NET errors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When using WebSocket to open my wss I sometimes see in the browser console ...

foo.js:557 WebSocket connection to 'wss://:9002/changes' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Other times I see...

WebSocket connection to 'wss://:9002/changes' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

However, in either case the onclose event is code 1006. Is there anyway in JavaScript I can differentiate between the invalid certificate and the down connection?

Comment: Catch and throw a custom more descriptive error from the server or simply just parse the returned error message in JavaScript looking for that text "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" or "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID".

Comment: It doesn't throw anything. Unfortunately it appears the useful error only exists on the console and not anywhere accessible by JavaScript

Comment: Some have suggested its a security feature of Chrome to not give the JavaScript code access to information about the network https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556398/how-to-catch-neterr-connection-refused