# Javascript: How to catch this Console Error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, error-handling, console

Javascript: How to catch this Console Error

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

I am unable to catch it by xhr.onerror  & try catch method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch net::ERR\_CONNECTION\_REFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556398/how-to-catch-neterr-connection-refused)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.