# JavaScript fetch ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED vs TypeError Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, typeerror, fetch-api

When using the JavaScript fetch API, the browser's console logs an error of `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, but the `catch` block of fetch returns a message of `TypeError Failed to fetch` when a server is offline.

#### Example

The following minimal fetch highlights the two error messages:

```js
fetch("https://localhost/get-something", {
    method: "POST"
}).then(resp => {
    console.log(resp)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("ERR:", err, err.name, err.message)
})
```

When running the fetch, the browser's console will have two errors:

```
POST https://localhost/get-something net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And

```
ERR: TypeError: Failed to fetch
// err.message will be "failed to fetch"
```

The generic `failed to fetch` message from the catch block is returned in instances other than a server being down. I'm more interested in the browser's console error of `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

#### Question

Is there a way to capture the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` value in a failed fetch call?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556398/how-to-catch-neterr-connection-refused

Comment: @Quentin not sure why that question is a dup. 1) It is using `XMLHttpRequest`; I'm using `fetch`. 2) No answer provided captures the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. 3) I'm already catching the error, but is is the "failed to fetch" error. Do you have an ideas on how to captures the connection refused error?

Comment: From the Mozilla Developer Network: The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

Comment: do not call https in localhost! is obvious you don't get results! is insecure to call then with exceptions https (if you resolve the issue by force passing https on localhost)

Comment: @Constantin - doesn't matter if you use `https` or `http`; same result.

Comment: use this experiment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73475945/5781320

Comment: There is no separate error response for ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, you have to handle in generic error response. Thanks!

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43061415/14738189

"if you host the websocket together with html, you can start a websocket at the beginning of the page. This ws must connect successfully since you can get the html. And listen to its close event to know the time when the server is not available. Or just build a server to check if ws server available on html server"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible as this kind of message is printed in the console from Chrome itself. Suppressing these types of messages has been debated for years, but the consensus seems to be that these kinds of messages are desirable.

you can only hide them from your client using the filter check this:
https://umaar.com/dev-tips/79-hide-network-console/